# Phase Portrait of DE's

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I graph the phase portrait of

$$ x' = x^2+y^2-2 \qquad y' = y-x^2 $$
?

Could someone provide some insight by hand or perhaps a computer-generated image?

Comment: Start by looking at where $x' = 0$ and $y' = 0$. Now divide the plane up into a number of regions depending on the sign of $x'$ and $y'$.

Comment: You might look at http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/nonlin/nonlin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x'=0$ when $x^2+y^2-2=0$, i.e., on the circle $x^2+y^2=2$. So outside the circle, $x'>0$ and inside the circle, $x'<0$. This tells you the "east-west" behavior of trajectories in those regions.

On the other hand, $y'=0$ on $y=x^2$ so above the parabola, $y'>0$ and below it $y'<0$. This tells you the "north-south" behavior of trajectories in those regions.

(The intersection of these curves are the fixed points of the system.)

Put all that info together to get a rough idea of the phase plane. Here's a picture:

[image]